# Handle SwapChainPanel in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, winui-3, winui

I have my xaml code

```
<ListView x:Name="ListVideo"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ScreenList}"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
              Grid.Row="1"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <controls:UniformGrid></controls:UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="White"
                      BorderBrush="White"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                    <SwapChainPanel x:Name="swapChain"
                                    
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate></ListView>
```

with `ScreenList` is type of `ObservableCollection`. So the question is how can I add new `SwapChainPanel` in the ListView?.

I intend to add `SwapChainPanel` item, and with each item I use DirectX to render video, so i want to get the object `SwapChainPanel` item in code-behind to process then.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is how can I add new SwapChainPanel in the ListView

You have placed SwapChainPanel in the Listview DataTemplate, and current listview `ItemsSource` is ObservableCollection. So you just need add new item into ObservableCollection, the listview will render new item automatically.

> so i want to get the object SwapChainPanel item in code-behind

You could get itemContainer with [ContainerFromItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem?view=winrt-22000) method, and find swapChain with name in [`ContentTemplateRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateroot?view=winrt-22000).

```
var container = MyList.ContainerFromItem(MyList.Items[0]) as ListViewItem;
var swapChain = (container.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid).FindName("swapChain");
```

**Update**

As the Hoka Biu comment below, you could also get swapChain instance within SwapChainPanel Loaded event.

```
<SwapChainPanel Loaded="swapChain_Loaded"/>

private void swapChain_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var swapChain = sender as SwapChainPanel;         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I find the other solution that I can get SwapChainPanel object by adding an Loaded event for SwapChainPanel item.

Comment: Sure, you could also get swapchain instance in the Loaded event, I have updated the case reply.